# Is there a way to change the .vagrand.d location (the location for vagrant boxes)?

Tags: vagrant

By default, vagrant extracts boxes to a users home drive - `%HOMEDRIVE%\.vagrant.d\boxes`. This is on a network location. While good for reliable storage, this is extremely slow.

How do I change the location of boxes?

Comment: It should be noticed that currently, in 2013, Vagrant saves only 300 MB of box info per box into .vagrant.d, and puts the full 2-3 GB VMs into VirtualBox's VM-folder!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Of course. Just change (or set) `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variable.

[Source: Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/u6dYmUMmHCY/vmXl_ghJmCQJ)

Comment: Im new on vagrant how I do that on windows 7?